# Symfony2: CRUD-generated functional test fails incorrectly

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

In a simple and slightly modified functional test generated by the CRUD generator, a crawler test fails incorrectly.  This is determined by examining the content in an external file created before the assertion. And by element inspection of the page.  And by manual running of jquery code `$("td:contains('Test')").length;` So why does the test fail?

#### Test class:

```
class ApplianceControllerTest extends WebTestCase {

    private $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = static::createClient(array(), array(
         ...
        ));
        $this->client->followRedirects();
    }

    public function testCompleteScenario() {
        // Create a new entry in the database
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/appliance/');
        $crawler = $this->client->click($crawler->selectLink('Create a new entry')->link());

        // Fill in the form and submit it
        $form = $crawler->selectButton('Create')->form(array(
            'appliance[appliance]' => 'Test',
                // ... other fields to fill
        ));

        $this->client->submit($form);
//        $crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();
        $content = $this->client->getResponse()->getContent();
        file_put_contents('somefile', $content);

        // Check data in the show view
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $crawler->filter('td:contains("Test")')->count(), 'Missing element td:contains("Test")');
}
```

#### Output:

> Missing element td:contains("Test") Failed asserting that 0 is greater
>   than 0.

#### Excerpt of captured content:

```
<div class="title">Appliance</div>
<div class="width40">

    <table class="record_properties">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <td>14</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Appliance</th>
                <td>Test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Enabled</th>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why did you comment out `$crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();`?

Comment: @mattexx: It was commented out because it threw an error: "LogicException: The request was not redirected."

Comment: hmm. Did you look into that error?

Comment: @mattexx: No, mostly 'cuz I wouldn't know where to look or what to do about it. The CRUD stuff is all pretty sparse.

Comment: hint: it indicates that your form submission was not successful.

Comment: @mattexx:I'd assumed that the contents indicated success.  What I've just now learned is that I need to remove the line `$this->client->followRedirects();` from __construct() and reinstate the line `$crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();`!! Curiously, I'd gotten away with all that before in 2.1.  You can post this as an answer and I'll accept it.  Your comment made me test the mod.

Comment: You got it. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comment thread:

You have commented out `$crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();` due to the error "LogicException: The request was not redirected." This error indicates that the form submission is not successful.

As you discovered, removing the line `$this->client->followRedirects();` from __construct() and reinstate the line `$crawler = $this->client->followRedirect();` fixes your test.